# What can a ranger 1/paladin 1 do with their spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, multi-classing, ranger, paladin

Paladins and rangers get their spellcasting at level 2, as they are half-casters. However, a ranger 1/paladin 1 would have the spell slots of a 1st-level full caster. Would this hypothetical character have any abilities they could use their spell slots on?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### You have no spell slots.

Even if [you add before dividing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79573/how-do-paladin-and-ranger-class-levels-add-up-for-multiclass-spellcasting/79574#79574) and `(1+1)/2 = 1`, you have no spell slots. This is because the multiclassing rule that grants Combined spell slots for multiple classes is in the “[Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting)” subsection of the “[Class Features](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#ClassFeatures)” section of Chapter 6 of the *Player’s Handbook*. Neither of your classes have granted you a Spellcasting class feature (yet), so the combined slot rules don’t apply to you:

> Once you have the Spellcasting feature from more than one class, use the rules below. If you multiclass but have the Spellcasting feature from only one class, you follow the rules as described in that class.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I skipped over that paragraph and looked right at the table. +1.

Comment: *"Neither of your classes have granted you a Spellcasting class feature,"* yet. I would add "yet" at the end of this part.

Comment: @Mołot Well, by the time they get a spell slot, they're no longer a 1/1 ranger/paladin.

Comment: @Nelson I agree. The point I was trying to make is that they get Spellcasting at 2nd level. Many people seem to think they are spellcasters from the beginning, which is not true and on the 1st level they are not spellcasters. Yet.

Comment: It's worth noting that your claim of adding before dividing is *not* the highest-voted answer there

Comment: @Exempt-Medic My reference was due to an old version of the original post before it got re-edited. I'll change "though" to "if" for clarity.

Comment: Amusingly, if read the other way you get an interesting situation for a fighter 2 rogue 2 combo. Both of those classes may or may not grant Spellcasting, depending on your third level archetype picks. Allowing it would mean you actually lose slots if you choose a non-casting archetype.